# Sync a sharepoint workspace with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using a sharepoint Workspace between different people, so I'm basicaly syncing a folder between pc's. Now my question is if any of you know how to sync between pc's and a folder on a sharepoint site. I cannot seem to figure this out!

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a document library on a SharePoint site and then give permissions (contribute or higher) to everyone who wants to share the files/folder. Once it's done, ask your users to navigate to the library on the SharePoint site and click on the "Sync to SharePoint Workspace" under library tab.
[image: Snapshot of a document library ribbon in SharePoint 2010]

Alternatively, Once you are done assigning permissions to the document library (or just a folder in it), users can directly add the document library from the workspace quick launch for Sharing. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose  for your purpose you should use oneDrive instead of SharePoint workspace. Pay attention that oneDrive is available in office 2013 or office 365. In 2010 version it's named SkyDrive!
look at these links:
 [Sync OneDrive for Business or site libraries to your computer](https://support.office.com/client/synchronize-your-OneDrive-for-Business-library-or-other-SharePoint-site-libraries-to-your-local-computer-23e1f12b-d896-4cb1-a238-f91d19827a16)
[Overview of OneDrive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn167720(v=office.15).aspx)